# How do I run a JAD/JAR in the Java ME SDK (Mac) Emulator from a Netbeans Web Project

Tags: java, netbeans, java-wireless-toolkit

I'm using Netbeans on Mac.

I have a web project that I'm developing, that communicates with a Java MIDlet that has already been developed.

In my project /web folder, I have a /client.jar (and .jad) that interacts with my web application. I'd like a way to be able to right-click on the jad, and say "Run as MIDlet", to bring up the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Java ME SDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/downloads/sdk30-mac-jsp-137878.html) which is based on Netbeans. And as this SDK is based on Netbeans I'm pretty sure that you can find a way to have directly those features in Netbeans.